# Finding nodes that partition a Graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, language-agnostic, partition

I have a non-directed graph that represents the connectivity between regions of a map. I'd like to identify groups of nodes (regions) that could be removed without creating graph partitions.

What I have tried:

Walking the tree (BFS, DFS...), storing the depths and selecting the nodes with the higher depth (O(n)). Once calculated, I can update the depths in O(~1) on each removal-addition by checking the depth of neighbour nodes (connectivity does not exceed a certain threshold)

Is there a cheaper way to do this? Also finding graph literature is also very hard if you don't know the academical term for the problem. My graphs are between 200 and 500 nodes.

Comment: What do you mean by "without creating graph partitions"?

Comment: Without creating a graph that is disconnected. That means, finding nodes that by removing keep the graph all connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find nodes which are **not** *articulation points*. Cf. this [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Articulation_point) for some algorithms allowing to solve the problem of detecting articulation points. See also [this page](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/articulation-points-or-cut-vertices-in-a-graph/). Finally, note some of these algorithms are already implemented in tools such as [igraph](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/igraph/docs/articulation.points).

PS: this is very similar to the problem identified by Vikram, but not exactly the same thing, since the focus is on nodes, and not links.

Comment: Awesome! thanks so much! Additionally seem that Bridge detection prohibitively expensive for my case since I need to try to find several nodes at once. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are solving can be reduced to [bridge finding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_%28graph_theory%29) problem in graph.

Algorithm :-

> 1. calculate all bridges in the graph using tarjan's method.
> 2. then remove a node which does not have bridge as a edge.
> 3. Then re-evaluate the bridges in subgraph of the removed node partitioned by bridges.
> 4. Continue doing 2 & 3 until there is no node to remove.

Comment: Finding bridges using Tarjan's method is expensive and would need to be done for every node I want to take out. Removing items from, let's say BFS, walk is cheaper.

Comment: @DiegoEcheverri actually both algorithms are similar if you notice carefully

Comment: Yes Vikram. You are right. I assumed finding a point that is not an articulation point would not require to do a full walk. But it does.